# 'Schema mismatch for input column 'Features': expected scalar or vector of String, got VarVector<Single> (Parameter 'inputSchema')'

Tags: c#, .net, k-means, ml.net

I'm want to implement the k-means clustering algorithm to clusterize a list of text files loaded from disk, and also using the silhouette method to determine the number of clusters.

The error I'm getting is `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Schema mismatch for input column 'Features': expected scalar or vector of String, got VarVector<Single> (Parameter 'inputSchema')'`

How can I solve the problem?

**Code**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Load text files from disk
    string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles("C:\\ExportedEmails\\", "*.txt");
    string[] textFiles = filePaths.Select(File.ReadAllText).ToArray();

    // Extract features from text files
    var textData = textFiles.Select((text, index) =>
    {
        int startIndex = text.IndexOf("Description: ") + "Description: ".Length;
        string description = text.Substring(startIndex);
        return new TextData { Text = description, Index = index };
    }).ToArray();

    // Initialize the MLContext
    var context = new MLContext();

    // Convert data to IDataView
    var data = context.Data.LoadFromEnumerable(textData);

    // Initialize the variables to store the silhouette scores
    var silhouetteScores = new double[10];

    // Iter
    for (int k = 2; k <= 10; k++)
    {
        // Create a new KMeansTrainer
        var pipeline = context.Transforms.Text.FeaturizeText("Text", "Features")
                .Append(context.Clustering.Trainers.KMeans(featureColumnName: "Features", numberOfClusters: k));

        var model = pipeline.Fit(data);
        var transformedData = model.Transform(data);

        // Compute the silhouette score
        var clusterAssignments = transformedData.GetColumn<uint>("PredictedLabel").ToArray();
        var clusterCenters = transformedData.GetColumn<float[]>("Centroid").ToArray();
        var features = transformedData.GetColumn<float[]>("Features").ToArray();
        var silhouetteScore = ComputeSilhouetteScore(features, clusterAssignments, clusterCenters);

        silhouetteScores[k - 2] = silhouetteScore;
    }

    // Find the number of clusters that maximizes the average silhouette score
    int optimalClusters = 0;
    double maxScore = double.MinValue;
    for (int i = 0; i < silhouetteScores.Length; i++)
    {
        if (silhouetteScores[i] > maxScore)
        {
            maxScore = silhouetteScores[i];
            optimalClusters = i + 2;
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine($"The optimal number of clusters is {optimalClusters}.");
}

private static double ComputeSilhouetteScore(float[][] features, uint[] clusterAssignments, float[][] clusterCenters)
{
    double silhouetteScore = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < features.Length; i++)
    {
        var a = ComputeAverageDistance(features[i], clusterAssignments[i], features, clusterAssignments);
        var b = ComputeMinimumDistance(features[i], clusterAssignments[i], clusterCenters);
        silhouetteScore += (b - a) / Math.Max(a, b);
    }
    return silhouetteScore / features.Length;
}

private static double ComputeAverageDistance(float[] feature, uint clusterAssignment, float[][] features, uint[] clusterAssignments)
{
    double distance = 0;
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < features.Length; i++)
    {
        if (clusterAssignments[i] == clusterAssignment)
        {
            distance += Distance(feature, features[i]);
            count++;
        }
    }
    return distance / count;
}

private static double ComputeMinimumDistance(float[] feature, uint clusterAssignment, float[][] clusterCenters)
{
    double minDistance = double.MaxValue;
    for (int i = 0; i < clusterCenters.Length; i++)
    {
        if (i != clusterAssignment)
        {
            minDistance = Math.Min(minDistance, Distance(feature, clusterCenters[i]));
        }
    }
    return minDistance;
}

private static double Distance(float[] feature1, float[] feature2)
{
    double distance = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < feature1.Length; i++)
    {
        distance += Math.Pow(feature1[i] - feature2[i], 2);
    }
    return Math.Sqrt(distance);
}


class TextData
{
    public string? Text { get; set; }
    public float[] Features { get; set; }
    public int Index { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the reason you're getting this error is you set the output column name to *Text* and input column name as *Features* in the `FeaturizeText` transform. I suspect you want the opposite. Take the Text column as input and generate a feature vector called *Features* which you can do by swapping the values in `FeaturizeText` or you can explicitly add parameter names (`FeaturizeText(outputColumnName: "Features", inputColumnName:"Text")`).

Check out the [FeaturizeText documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.ml.textcatalog.featurizetext?view=ml-dotnet#microsoft-ml-textcatalog-featurizetext(microsoft-ml-transformscatalog-texttransforms-system-string-system-string)) for more details.